# How to iterate over a treemap using the entry set?

Tags: java

I wrote the following code for iterating over a treemap using the entryset method.

```
Set<Entry<String, String>> tmap1 = tmap.entrySet();
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = tmap1.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

This does not give me the desired results.
Can someone fix this.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: And what would the desired effects be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Java, there is a more concise way to write that iteration:

```
for (Entry<String, String> e : tmap.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

It's hard to make further suggestions since you don't specify what the desired result is, and in what way your current code fails to produce it. Please expand the question, and I'll expand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to write the iteration, as pointed in aix's answer, but your code looks fine. Maybe the problem is that the elements are not printed in the order in which they were inserted? If that's the case, then make sure that your `Map` is a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: Since he is using a `TreeMap` my guess is that he wants natural ordering.